# How to show form components based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am having a form which is having 3 forms within and each child form will have its separate submit button and the parent will have its own submit button. I want to show the form one by one like initially only 1st form will be shown then on clicking continue 1st and 2nd form will be displayed and then after again clicking on continue 1st,2nd,3rd form will be displayed. All 3 forms are on the same page in 3 different components.
The code structure is like this: [Codebox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mclean-9vndy?file=/src/App.js)

Also am facing an error

```
<form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>
```

Because form within form, is there a way to achieve the same without this is error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a state to control it: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dawn-zlh5x?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [formNumber, setFormNumber] = useState(0);
  const initialValues = { name: "", email: "", number: "" };
  const onSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(" Final Values", values);
  };
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form className="space-y-7">
          {formNumber >= 0 && <Form1 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          {formNumber >= 1 && <Form2 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          {formNumber >= 2 && <Form3 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          <div className="flex flex-row-reverse">
            <button type="button" onClick={() => setFormNumber(formNumber + 1)}>
              Continue
            </button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you help me in fixing this error "<form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form>"

Comment: Because using <form> tag inside another <form>. Update it and the warning will disappear

Comment: Because i want it to function that way only, can't we use form inside form?

Comment: we can use. Just ignore warning

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

I came up something like this, we can keep the count of form number and add one every time we click continue. But there needs to be validation before continue button enabled and plus, you need to handle the last step extra.

```
export default function App() {
  const [formNumber, setFormNumber] = useState(0)
  const initialValues = { name: "", email: "", number: "" };
  const onSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(" Final Values", values);
  };
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form className="space-y-7">
          {formNumber === 0 && <Form1 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          {formNumber === 1 && <Form2 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          {formNumber === 2 && <Form3 initialValues={initialValues} />}
          <div className="flex flex-row-reverse">
            <button  onClick={()=> setFormNumber(formNumber + 1)} type="button">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Instead of using Form components, you can make it a single form with 3 inputs. That would be easier I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `useState` to save the index of current form, then create a function to change current index and pass it as a function to the child components!
use this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import Form1 from "./Form1";
import Form2 from "./Form2";
import Form3 from "./Form3";

export default function App() {
  const initialValues = { name: "", email: "", number: "" };
  const onSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(" Final Values", values);
  };
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  const nextIndex = ()=>{
    setIndex(index+1);
  }
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue }) => (
        <Form className="space-y-7">
          {
            index==0?<Form1 initialValues={initialValues} handleIndex={nextIndex}/>:
            index==1?<Form2 initialValues={initialValues} handleIndex={nextIndex}/>:
            <Form3 initialValues={initialValues} handleIndex={nextIndex}/>
          }
          <div className="flex flex-row-reverse">
            <button type="button">Continue</button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

now, in each child use `handleIndex` function to go to the next form!